# Bottom border/outline disappears ion-button inside ion-card

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying put ion-button inside the card.
But it's bottom border/outline disappears, as shown below.
It comes back when I click the button.
Why is this happening?

[image: this image shows the disappearance]

the image on top is loading late and causing this how do i wait for the image to load before rendering the page
or occupy the image space for image is loaded

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML code, you are using.

Comment: i got the problem, the img on top is loading late and pushing the card down is causing this.

Comment: i cant show the code as its proprietary

Answer (score 0):

Found a messy fix.

```
<img src="..." (load)="homeImageLoaded = true"/>

<ion-buttons *ngIf="homeImageLoaded">
 <button> </button>
</ion-buttons>
```